# Fixing a popover to a fixed navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a popover linked to an element on a fixed navbar, when the popover is visible it is fixed to the position of the navbar.
So when I scroll the popover still hovers on the same position of the body and does not move with the navbar.
I'm trying to figure out how to make the popover scroll with the navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set the `data-container` property to navbar
So instead of `data-container="body"` it will be 
`data-container="nav"`